# How to insert lists inside a list that outputs in the following format : [a, b, c] => [ [c], [b, c], [a, b, c]]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that takes in the number of arguments and returns a list in the following format: [a, b, c] => [ [c], [b, c], [a, b, c]]

```
   def generate_list(arg):
     list = []
     for item in arg:
        list.append(item)
     return list

print(generate_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

I know the above is not correct. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: don't use python keyword `list` to name a variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it with the negative slicing:

```
[lst[-(k + 1):] for k in range(len(lst))]
```

Here is a sample run:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [lst[-(k + 1):] for k in range(len(lst))]
[['c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: beautiful solution but that doesn't have the correct order of the second sublist (assuming order matters)

Comment: @aydow, could you elaborate, please?

Comment: your `generate_list([1,2,3])` gives `[[3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. the OP wanted `[[3], [3, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: @aydow I don't think that's the case following the format `[a, b, c] => [[c], [b, c], [a, b, c]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def generate_list( arg ) :
    arg.reverse()
    output = [[arg[0]]]
    for a in arg[1:] :
        output.append( [a] + output[-1] )
    return output

print( generate_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) )
```

for me it outputs:

```
[[5], [4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps as expected. I was wondering whether you might be able to explain this bit of the code:  output.append( [a] + output[-1] )

Comment: @RizwanRahmanRenesa the current element of `arg` in variable `a` is converted to the list `[a]` and prepended to the last element already in the `output`, the last element in the list has the index `-1`, like "second from the end".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `l` is your list -

```
l = [a, b, c]
```

Could try something like -

```
[l[i-1:] for i in range(len(l), 0, -1)]
```

O/P-

```
[['c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```